# SuperDevMode over regular GWT Dev Mode

Tags: java, gwt

How is SuperDevMode faster than the former GWT Dev Mode?

When it has to do compile over and over again? Is there any performance gain in terms of development time for using SuperDevMode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SuperDevMode is not (yet) faster than DevMode (though it actually depends), but that's not the point.

SuperDevMode keeps the compiler warmed up, so re-compiling is faster than compiling from scratch. The next GWT version will allow incremental compilation, making it even faster.

DevMode on the other hand can be heavily slowed down when you cross JSNI boundaries (JSNI methods are executed in the browser, Java methods in the DevMode JVM, and you communicate through TCP between them).

But as I said, that's not the point.

The point is that DevMode stopped working in Safari a while ago, in Firefox starting last week with the Firefox 27 update, and soon in Chrome too, leaving only IE (for how long?). SuperDevMode doesn't use plugins or private browser APIs, so it won't suddenly stop working.

SuperDevMode is the way forward, and not for performance or productivity reasons.

Comment: But its very hard to debug with SuperDevMode compared to DevMode

Answer (score 0):

I have core i3 and at my machine site on SuperDevMode work much faster than DevMode. By superdevmode you can't debug code in eclipse, but in my case it was not too uncomfortable.